# How to sync web and mobile mysql database using amazon app sync

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-appsync

I am creating an application that works online and offline. I am using MYSQL database in a web application (Nodejs) and mobile application (Android) but I am not sure how I can sync data using AWS app sync. Can you please help me how I can do it using app sync feature?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [Amplify DataStore](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/datastore), it does not currently support RDS. As of writing, to use the built-in sync capabilities of data store, you need to store data in DynamoDB.

If you must use SQL, and are willing to not use data store, you can use AppSync and the RDS data source type to create APIs that interact with Aurora serverless databases on RDS. In this model, you can use the same queries/mutations/subscriptions to build real-time applications but you would need to use another tool or custom logic to implement offline sync.

Comment: You wouldn't happen to have any writeups or details about this? :D